# How do I move blocks, for example to the middle, to the left or right in my own theme?

Tags: php, css, drupal, themes

This is my theme:

[image]

It looks like HTML. How can I relocate the blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you are using drupal 7:

Go to Structure -> pages -> search for your page -> edit -> content -> then move your blocks within the layout you designed.

Answer (score 0):

Go on

```
/admin/structure/block
```

There you can relocate blocks on regions in your theme.